# MongoDB calculating currency exchange on the fly

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to get results from collection based on min/max price, but user might want to search in GBP, and document has a USD.

I've been thinking about querying Exchange collection from Object and exchange pricing, but 
since mongodb doesn't allow me to use "db" inside $where function it cannot work like this.

Objects collection (one record):

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5473572cf1a76349020041c6"),
  [...]
  "pricing" : {
    "basic" : 9470,
    "currency" : "USD"
  }
  [...]
}
```

Currency exchange collection (one record, USD‹—›EUR):

```
{
  "_id" : "USD",
  "rate" : 11344,
  "rateReverse" : 8815
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to not.

I actually work in this field and recently had to implement VAT and pricing for many EU countries as well the as the US, albeit in SQL but still, same rules normally apply.

Instead you set the currencies on the product upon save. Yes, the first thing you will say is: "what happens if the currency changes before the price?"

In other applications of this sort I have created I have used a weekly cronjob which actually goes through every product slowly throughout the week updating prices.

In otehr applications the prices were always vetted and monitored by a human. It is for this reason I do not make this cronjob more frequent. If they (the prices) flucuate heavily this could cause 10,000's of products to need vetting all at once, as such it is broken down over the week. Besides, significant currency change over the period of one week is extremely, borderline, unlikely.

To break down the work created by currency pricing and make it even more automated it was considered that anything over or under 5% of the conversion to be significant and flag the price, this means most of the prices are automated in currency changing.

We did originally used to do on the spot calculations for MySQL but it got really slow, especially when loading the currency tables JOINs.

Comment: I've been thinking about getting whole collection of currencies (~ 30 documents), and putting it into $where query, but I have serious doubts about performance for such solution, but it's gonna give me all possibilities that I currently need.

Comment: @retest a $where would kill your system and quite possibly induce security threats due to unsanitised input

Comment: Thanks for reply, I've been getting to this point from wrong direction :). Resolved by putting $or with calculated max price value for each currency that matters